# How to display list on two different sites in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, share

We have a list that we want to display on two different Sharepoint (SP2013) sites. In Sharepoint 2010 there were an option to share lists across sites through Sharepoint designer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TntwRm78b_4

Problem is that it seems that Microsoft has removed this option in Sharepoint 2013. Do anyone have any suggestions how to do this in the newer version?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If You want to display the content of the list You can use the Content Search Web Part or Search Results web part in order to show the elements from the list. First create a Result Source and enter the address to the list in it and which elements/Content Types it should return, and then configure Your web part to use that Result Source.
Best Regards, Magnus